# Ruby win32ole - how to determine the OLE class type, whether the OLE class supports a method

Tags: ruby, outlook, win32ole

I am using Ruby 1.8. Using the WIN32OLE module -

1) How do I determine the class name of an OLE object instance?
2) How can I tell whether an object instance supports a particular method?

In an Outlook automation script, I am trying to delete the items in the 'Deleted Items' folder which are older than 21 days. For mail items, I want to use the ReceivedTime property, but in order to do that, I need to check whether the item is actually a MailItem instance.

For the second, the best I have been able to come up with is (really slow):

```
def MethodExists(obj, methodName)
  obj.ole_methods.each{|method|
    if (method.name == methodName)
      return true
    end
  }
  return false
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With specific regard to WIN32OLE objects...

*How do I determine the class name of an OLE object instance?*

```
object.ole_obj_help.name
```

*How can I tell whether an object instance supports a particular method?*

```
object.ole_methods.collect!{ |x| x.to_s }.include?( 'MethodName' )
```

Comment: I think object.ole_methods.any? { |x| x.to_s == "MethodName" } would be a bit more concise. Or #detect, that would be good too.

Comment: @MikeWoodhouse: The code came from [this link](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2009/02/win32ole-objects-class-names-and.html). I'd personally do `ole_methods.collect(&:to_s)` (ie no bang, and use Symbol#to_proc unless you're on Ruby 1.8.6).

Answer (score -3):

1. `obj.class`
2. :

   ```
   if obj.respond_to?(methodName)
       #do your work
   end
   ```